# How to prove $\sqrt[3]{7}$+$\sqrt{5}$ is irrational?

Tags: polynomials, irrational-numbers

We are learning the rational root theorem right now. It is pretty clear how to prove a number is irrational when we know how to construct a polynomial that only includes integer and has the irrational number as a root *(rational root theorem)*. However, if it comes to sum of two number with different power, it is pretty hard to construct the polynomial. Is there a general way to construct polynomial? Or is there any alternative ways to prove this question?

Comment: Ouline for getting polynomial:Let $x=\sqrt[3]{7}$+$\sqrt{5}$. Then $x-\sqrt{5}=\sqrt[3]{7}$. So

$$(x-\sqrt{5})^3=7$$

That is, $x^3-3\sqrt{5}x^2-3\sqrt{5}x-5\sqrt{5}=7$ \\

That is, $x^3-7=3\sqrt{5}x^2+3\sqrt{5}x+5\sqrt{5}$

 Squaring and rearranging, we get a required polynomial.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, the question [Prove $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational](/q/1316335), in the "Related" section on the right side, is quite similar to yours, and I believe can at least to some extent answer your questions. Also, that question is linked to [How to prove $\sqrt3 + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is a irrational number?](/q/1785159), which has additional methods which can be used to solve your problem.